# SQL Server Finding Duplicates

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a table as follows

```
Employee    RecNumber
Joe Bloggs  123456
Joe Bloggs  123456
Bob Bloggs  123457
Dup Bloggs  123456
```

And I just want to return all Rec Numbers where 2 People have had the same RecNumber which shouldn't happen.
Note that one person can have same request number multiple times I just want returned where 2 people have the same rec Number

So all I want returned is

```
123456
```

Comment: Can you clarify please? Add another row `Bob Bloggs`, `123457` - you don't want that returned right, since it's the same person (well, a person with the same name, hopefully you don't have two people named Bob Bloggs, but in general that's a terrible way to tell individuals apart, since some names are quite common).

Comment: Can you also specify whether you want 2 or more people with the same RecNumber, since some people think that means you care only about EXACTLY 2. <shrug>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select record_number
  from my_table
  group by record_number
  having count(distinct employee) > 1
```

Comment: Interesting take on it, I suspect the sample data doesn't truly allow us to distinguish what he meant with his word problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.RECNUMBER,COUNT(B.EMPLOYEE)
(SELECT DISTINCT RECNUMBER FROM YOURTABLE) A,
YOURTABLE B
WHERE A.RECNUMBER = B.RECNUMBER
GROUP BY A.RECNUMBER
HAVING COUNT(B.EMPLOYEE)=2;
```

Comment: Why = 2? What if they have 3 or 4 or 5 or more?

Comment: Right but do you think his table only has 4 rows? He only shows 2 matches in his sample data, but I think we can extrapolate.

Comment: "I just want returned where 2 people have the same rec Number" . I followed this one..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT RecNumber FROM Table GROUP BY RecNumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RecNumber FROM [a table] 
 GROUP BY RecNumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Or perhaps

```
SELECT RecNumber FROM (SELECT RecNumber, Employee
  FROM [a table] 
 GROUP BY RecNumber, Employee HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS x;
```

Comment: This will just return all duplicate recNumber im looking if 2 employees have the same

Comment: That's why I asked for clarification, since your sample data is mildly ambiguous. I also added the alternate interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like that, i think it's working  :

```
use *DATABASE_NAME*
go
select *Your_Field*, Nbre=count(*Your_Field*) from *TABLE_NAME* 
group by *Your_Field*
having count(*Your_Field*)>1
order by 2 desc
```

Enjoy